# MariaDB How to avoid error NOT NULL DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

i m trying to load a DB in my local server XAMPP but it keeps giving me this error.

**My table**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions_client_view` (

   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `surname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `actualcredit` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
   `amount` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
   `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `error` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**ERROR**

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 361239: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   `amount` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',    `date' at line 4

Comment: is your database populated ?

Comment: @ZombieChowder this table not

Comment: The code in the error message is not the same as in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions_client_view` (

   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `surname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `actualcredit` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
   `amount` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
   `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `error` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```